# How can I turn off tablet mode Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have currently updated my machine to Windows 10 and wanted to explore tablet mode. However, I do not know how to turn it off once I turn it on.

I am a bit afraid that my desktop will get “stuck” on tablet mode.

How do I quit tablet mode in Windows 10?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the "Settings" app:

1. System
2. Tablet mode
3. When this device automatically switches tablet mode on or off
4. Don’t ask me and don’t switch

---

From the "Action Center":

> 4. To Turn On Tablet Mode
> 5. Click/tap on the Action Center (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) system icon in the taskbar notification area.
> 6. At the bottom of the Action Center, click/tap on the Tablet mode button to toggle it on (blue) or off (gray) for what you want.
>
> [image]

Source [Tablet Mode - Turn On or Off in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3755-tablet-mode-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I have updated the answer, as previous instruction is not valid for current Windows versions

Answer (score -2):

Playing around in Tablet mode, I found this way to get back to Windows mode:
Start >
Control Panel >
System & Security >
Security & Maintenance >
Recovery >
PC Settings >
(Find a Setting) - type in Tablet Mode >

Comment: This seems to be just a slower way of editing exactly the same setting that the accepted answer already does.