# Windows 10 complete remove tablet mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, tablet-mode

Windows 10 detect my workstation custom PC as a tablet device and the Tablet mode is visible in PC settings. 2 applications, Bluestacks, and Droid4X detect my PC as a tablet device. I tried to unplug some USB cable but it's not helping. My monitor is ASUS gaming monitor with Nvidia 3D vision. I had disabled Tablet mode in settings but some applications still detect my PC as a tablet device. How can i fully remove tablet mode from my PC and make Tablet mode disappear from PC settings?

Comment: I assume you already know how to switch tablet mode off and on?

Comment: Relate/Possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/949261/how-can-i-turn-off-tablet-mode-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: hello. you don't understand. i'm looking a way to completely remove tablet mode and make it disappear from the settings. the link you gave me is not a correct solution how to remove tablet mode and its detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tablet mode is a part of Windows 10 for the new Universal Platform it would be impossible to remove it; however you do have the option to turn it off in Settings.

Comment: ok. i have contacted both app company and they said they wasn't able to find the problem. they said tablet device wasn't detected on Windows 10 and the popup message about tablet device won't appear. Bluestacks will turn on hardware keyboard if tablet device wasn't detected. mine always turn off because of tablet mode.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. If your talking about how the android emulators behave then these are pretty standard and will work a specific way regardless of your windows set-up (With respect to keyboards anyway). Also, You may want to make your question clearer as if it is about the android emulators it should be more direct to this as an issue

Comment: yeah, but about the hardware keyboard begin turned off in android emulator isn't normal and the developer wasn't able to find the problem. popup message that said i'm using a tablet device isn't normal. i reinstalled Windows 10 and the problem still present so that's why i need help.

Comment: It could just be an incomparability with Bluestacks and Windows 10. If you have Tablet Mode switched off in your Windows 10 Settings then your computer is literally a PC. As Bluestacks runs on older versions of Windows doubt it would detect the presence of tablet mode anyway. I havent used the later version of Bluestacks but if you can access the android settings you can disable the onscreen keyboard